# Search a text document and apply attributes to results

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a Google Docs document with short phrases delimited by "@" symbols. I want to write a script to traverse the entire document, find these "@"-delimited phrases, remove the "@" symbols, and make the phrase underlined. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Phrases will be alpha only, and will be two or more words.

e.g.:

> @Dear Sir@, @I am@ ready to aid you @to the@ limit at getting the linen @you will@ need. @I can@ meet you in Erie @by the@ middle of May @with the@ main data. That @will not be@ too late will it? @Yours truly@,

**Addendum**

This is the code I've tried so far

```
function convertUnderline() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var foundElement;
  var foundText;

  foundElement = body.findText("@[a-zA-Z ]+[a-zA-Z]@");
  foundText = foundElement.getElement().asText().setUnderline(true);
  body.replaceText("@", "");
}
```

This works fine for finding and underlining the first match. I'm not certain how to traverse the rest of the document, though. I'm not keen on replacing all the "@" symbols afterward, but it seems that the regexp engine in Google Apps Scripts [doesn't support backreferences](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) (see item "\1" under **Escape sequences**).

Answer (score 0):

Grant, welcome to stack-overflow. It is normal protocol in these parts to lay down some code you have tried and are not doing so great with, then ask for some help with the bits you are struggling with.

Perhaps in this case good place to start would be "findText()" in the [apps-script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#findText(String)), or use something like [replaceText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#replaceText(String,String)).

You are also welcome to check out my [sidebar tool](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1MQ9EzoAvyi7yFvh_VGpT5ziayEOWpIMhYUHzqztqcvo/edit?usp=sharing) that does something very similar, but with the text highlighted rather than using "@".

Alternatively there is the below code which picks up all the words into an array. Then iterates the document text setting underlines based on offset coordinates calculated from the length of each item in the array. With working example [found here.](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1GyZ5yJ6PaJhoOjljdRe2M5q_3eDcO2zvB9xP8XJqXDk/edit?usp=sharing)

```
function convertUnderline() {

  var bodyTextElement = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().editAsText();;
  var textArr = bodyTextElement.getText().split(/(?=@)/g);  
  var cursorStartPosition = 0


  var attributes = {};
  attributes[DocumentApp.Attribute.UNDERLINE] = true;

  for (var i = 0; i <  textArr.length-1; i ++){
    var textLength = textArr[i].length;  
    if(textArr[i].indexOf('@ ') < 0){
      bodyTextElement.editAsText().setAttributes(cursorStartPosition,cursorStartPosition + textLength, attributes)
    }
    cursorStartPosition += textArr[i].length;
    bodyTextElement.replaceText("@", " ");
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, Jason. Thank you for your response. I've updated my question to include the code I've tried. I had already read the documentation on "findText()" and "replaceText()" in order to put together the modest amount of code. There seems to be something in the "findText(searchPattern, from)" documentation that could be what I'm looking for, but I'm not grasping what the documentation is saying, and without an example included, I'm lost.

Thank you for sharing your sidebar tool. Unfortunately, I'm not sure what I'm looking at when I load the document.

Comment: Hey, Grant. When I run your code it works on all of the instances of @ and makes the text underlined as you expect. This is the document I used. The code is in the appscript.https://docs.google.com/document/d/1GyZ5yJ6PaJhoOjljdRe2M5q_3eDcO2zvB9xP8XJqXDk/edit

Comment: Hi, Jason. Oddly, when I run the code on the same text, the entire text gets underlined rather than just the delimited bits. I feel I should be able to make the regexp non-greedy, but the documentation for the "U" flag that I've found is vague. Any suggestions?

Comment: I found that the setAttributes() method carries to arguments as co-ordinates. This made is possible to calculate which words should be underlined based on their position. I updated my answer. Please click that you except my answer if you like it. :)

Comment: Hi, Jason. I don't know why I'm getting different results from yours. When I run your code, the individual instances of the delimited text get underlined rather than the whole thing (the problem I was having with my original code), but I'm getting an extra underlined space both before and after the found text. I've committed as much time as I feel I can for this solution. I appreciate your help, but I'm going to look for a different solution. Thank you! :-)